# Раскрытие полного изображения при клике на миниатюру

Tags: javascript, html

Есть миниатюра изображения и полное изображение одной и той же картинки. Нужно раскрывать полное изображение через миниатюру. Нажал на миниатюру - развернулось полное изображение, нажал на полное - появилась миниатюра. Как GIF-изображения во ВКонтакте.

Код:

```
function expand(num, src, t_src)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('doc_' + num);
    el.innerHTML =
            '<a href="' + src + '" name="expandfunc"  onclick="expand(' + num + ',' + src + ',' + t_src + '); return false;"><img src="' +
            (src : t_src) + '" /></a>';
}
```

Но консоль ругается на скобку в 9 строке.

Comment: "на 9 строке" то есть 7 строке.

Comment: а вы уверены, что ваш код будет работать? функция какая-то странная. может лучше использовать велосипед, который придумали другие: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/

Comment: Должен работать, видел пример работоспособности, но сейчас сайт умер. А этот велосипед мне не нужен, ведь мне нужно открывать картинку в теле объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*консоль ругается* - конечно, ругается, потому что конструкция `(src : t_src)` синтаксически неверна. Объект создаётся так: `{src : t_src}`, но в вопросе достаточно использовать просто `t_src`.

Второй проблемой является то, что в `expand(' + num + ',' + src + ',' + t_src + ')` отсутствуют кавычки (для обозначения при вызове функции `expand` того, что это строки) вокруг `src` и `t_src`.

Третьей проблемой является то, что в будущем вызове `expand` нужно `src` и `t_src` поменять местами.

В итоге, строка кода должна выглядеть так:

```
el.innerHTML = '<a href="' + src + '" name="expandfunc" onclick="expand(' +
        num + ',\'' + t_src + '\',\'' + src + '\'); return false;"><img src="' +
        t_src + '" /></a>';
```

Полный пример:

```js
function expand(num, src, t_src)
{
    var el = document.getElementById('doc_' + num);
    el.innerHTML =
        '<a href="' + src + '" name="expandfunc" onclick="expand(' + num + ',\'' + t_src + '\',\'' + src + '\'); return false;"><img src="' + t_src + '" /></a>';
}
```

```html
<div id="doc_1">
    <a href="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png" onclick="expand(1, 'http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png', 'http://waytoeast.ru/images/page_bg.jpg'); return false;">
        <img src="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Однако выглядит код очень криво, не говоря уж о том, что использование `onclick` считается устаревшим.

Можно использовать `.addEventListener()`. Да, кода получается больше и это не будет работать в старых IE, но зато всё читабельно, раздельно и готово к будущим расширениям/доработкам:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDomReady, false);

function onDomReady()
{
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle_img');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    {
        var thisLink = links[i];
        thisLink.addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            handleLinkClick(event, thisLink);
        });
    }
}
    
function handleLinkClick(event, link)                                                               
{
    var currentSrc = link.href;
    var toggleSrc = link.getAttribute("data-img");
    var img = link.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.src = toggleSrc;
    link.href = toggleSrc;
    link.setAttribute("data-img", currentSrc);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<div id="doc_1">
    <a href="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png" class="toggle_img" data-img="http://waytoeast.ru/images/page_bg.jpg">
        <img src="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Если использовать jQuery, то код будет короче:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.toggle_img').on('click', function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        var currentSrc = this.href;
        var toggleSrc = $this.data("img");
        var img = $this.find('img')[0];
        img.src = toggleSrc;
        this.href = toggleSrc;
        $this.data("img", currentSrc);
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="doc_1">
    <a href="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png" class="toggle_img" data-img="http://waytoeast.ru/images/page_bg.jpg">
        <img src="http://waytoeast.ru/units/unit1.png"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

Какой из трёх способов использовать - дело ваше, но я рекомендую 2 и 3 способы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за разъяснения, все понял. Хотел использовать третий метод, но **TypeError: $(...).on is not a function**. Заменил на **$('.toggle_img').click(function()** - ошибок нет, но клик по картинке заменяет миниатюру на /undefined. Повторный клик работает.

Comment: @gm-111 скорее всего вы используете очень старую версию jQuery (старее `1.7`). Если это так, то вам нужна версия `1.7`+. В ответе используется версия `2.1.1`

Comment: да, проскакивала мысль на счет версий. Заменил на 1.7.2, все работает. Боялся, что остальные функции отвалятся, но нет, все хорошо. Еще один вопрос, можно ли сделать, что бы клик по одной картинке открывал певую картинку, и закрывал вторую, если она открыта?

Comment: Любая. Вот смотрите http://jsfiddle.net/zLmw2frb/ открываем первую картинку - она раскрывается, после нажимаем на третью картинку - третья раскрывается, а первая должна закрываться. То есть в раскрытом виде может быть только одна картинка.

Comment: @gm-111 если переделать исходный HTML, то всё упрощается. В том числе и эта задача становится не сложной. [Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLmw2frb/1/).

Comment: Костыли-костылики. Ладно, пусть будет так. Спасибо, еще раз.

Comment: @gm-111 на здоровье. Изменённая структура HTML в моём последнем примере - это как раз не костыли, а нормальный подход, без постоянной смены `src` и `href` и с упрощающимся JS кодом.

Comment: Даже не знаю. Хотя, я не программист, что бы судить об этом. Все-таки отвалились мои функции от перехода на 1.7.2. Может можно как-то застрелить двух зайцев и остаться на версии 1.4.2?

Comment: @gm-111 есть плохой вариант - использовать jQuery Migrate, и нормальный вариант - переписать код и начать использовать `1.11.0` или `2.1.0`+. Нормальный вариант, конечно, годится только если проект ваш или же руководство готово потратить на это время и деньги.

Comment: Да, я тоже за то, что бы переписать, но я не умею и много работы нужно проделать. А разве вашу функцию нельзя переписать под 1.4.2? Там вроде ничего сверхъестественного не используется.

Comment: @gm-111 судя по документации, достаточно `.on('click', ` заменить на `.click(` . Все остальные используемые методы появились в `1.0` - `1.4.3`. И если на то уж пошло, взгляните на jQuery Migrate.

Comment: Так не работает. Мигрэйт тоже. Ладно, хрен с ним. Достало меня это.